Does Apple BNNS copy weight data internally? Can I safely free my weight buffer afterward?
I'm working with Apple's BNNS framework to implement neural networks. I'm using the BNNSFilterCreateLayerFullyConnected function to create fully connected layers. I have a few questions regarding weight data handling:

Does BNNS Filter factory methods like BNNSFilterCreateLayerFullyConnected internally copy the weight data I provide into its own buffer? Or does it simply reference my original weight buffer?
If it does copy the data, can I safely free my original weight buffer after the layer is created? I want to ensure proper memory management and avoid potential issues.

I haven't been able to find definitive information in Apple's documentation. Any insights or clarifications on this would be greatly appreciated.
